# Problem retrieving data from the PostgreSQL database using Golang

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to retrieve data from Postgresql database using Golang. I have successfully inserted values several times but to retrieve them seem to be a problem. I do not know what I am not doing right.

Below is my function to retrieve data from the database

```
func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    
        if r.Method != "GET" {
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(405), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
            return
        }
    
    // viewing all values
    stmt := `SELECT * FROM person`
    rows, err := db.Query(stmt)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    var persons []Person
    for rows.Next() {
        var p Person
        err = rows.Scan(&p.id, &p.firstname, &p.lastname, &p.email, &p.gender, &p.country)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            panic(err)

        }
        persons = append(persons, p)
    }
    

    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "browseall.html", persons)
    defer rows.Close()

}
```

template looks like this

```
<body>
    <h1>Information about all persons</h1>
    <hr>

            
        Lastname : {{.firstname}}<br>
                Lastname : {{.lastname}}<br>
                Email : {{.email}}<br>
                Gender : {{.gender}}<br>    
                Country : {{.country}}<br>
        <a href="">Edit</a><br>
        <a href="">Delete</a><br>
            
    <hr>

     
    {{if .}}
      <h3>{{.}}</h3>
    {{end}}

    

</body>
```

Comment: You need to [export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the fields of the `Person` type to be able to use them inside the template.

Comment: Note that `templates.ExecuteTemplate` returns an error, if you would check that it would tell you that the fields don't exist (because the template cannot access unexported fields). Also note that `defer rows.Close()` at the end of the function makes no sense, either use it after getting the `rows` value and checking the `err`, or don't use `defer` and just invoke `rows.Close` directly (but then you need to do that at every return of the enclosing function). The `database/sql` package has many examples, take a look at them, and also check out https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements.

Comment: And your template is referring to the fields directly without first looping over the slice value that you pass in to the template, please read the https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/ documentation to learn how to properly use templates in Go.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have done all you pointed out and my code is working well. I`m so grateful.